# How to find common smallest number in two arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays that I need to sort and find the lowest number that occurs in both arrays. If there is no equality then it should return `-1`, if there is equality then it should return that number.

Here is my the code I have got so far

```
public int solution(int[] A, int[] B)
{
    int minA = A.Min();// Get minimum number of array A
    int minB = B.Min();// Get minimum number of array B

    if (minA == minB)// If both arrays have the same smallest number            
        return minA;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

The problem is it is only checking for equality of the lowest number and if it does not match then it returns. How do I get it to look at the next lowest number?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are trying to get the common minimum number (Intersection). So you can use `Intersect` in this case.

```
int[] arrA = {100, 102, 99, 107};
int[] arrB = {103, 102, 99, 105, 106, 109};

var commonNumbers = arrA.Intersect(arrB).ToArray();
return commonNumbers.Any() ? commonNumbers.Min() : -1);
```

Comment: +1, but while I'm always railing against people calling `ToList()` when not needed in answers on this site, this is a case where I would use it, as otherwise the two uses of `commonNumbers` will do the intersection calculation twice. Change it to `arrA.Intersect(arrB).ToList()` and it'll only need to actually find that intersected set once.

Comment: `commonNumbers as int[]`. What makes for that possibility?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to approach this problem is to sort the array first, you should try:

```
public int solution(int[] A, int[] B) 
{  
    //Sorts the array
    Array.Sort(A)
    Array.Sort(B)

    //store the array positions
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;

    While(i < Array.Length(A) && j < Array.Length(B)) //If any array ends before finding the equality, the while ends and the code return -1;
    {
        if(A[i] == B[j])
        {
            return A[i];
        }

        //if the element from A is larger than the element from B, you have to go up an element in B
        if(A[i] > B[j])
        {
            j++;
        }     

        //if the element from B is larger than the element from A, you have to go up an element in A
        if(A[i] < B[j])
        {
            i++;
        }
    }

    return -1;         
}
```

I didn't tested, but think it should work.

Comment: Nice, cleaner than my pseudocode.  The equality comparison should be == and the While loop should loop < rather than <= to the Length (zero based indices).

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
public int solution(int[] A, int[] B)
{
    var common = A.Intersect(B).ToList();

    return common.Count > 0 ? common.Min() : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In pseudocode:

```
sort array A in ascending order
sort array B in ascending order

set elementB to the first element in B

for all elements in A

  if (elementA == elementB)
    return elementA

  while (elementA > elementB)
    try to get the next element from B

    if there are no more elements in B
      return -1

    if (elementA == elementB)
      return elementA
  end while

  // elementA is less than elementB
end for

return -1
```

In English:

Go through the A list and compare each value with the current value in B.  If they match, we're done.

If the value in B is smaller than A, then get the next value from B (because the numbers are sorted from small to large, there will never be a B value that matches the current A).

Keep grabbing the next B value until it is equal to A (we're done) or it is bigger than A (we need to grab the next A value to see if it catches up with the new B).

If we hit the end of either list, there are no matches.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is search the both pre-minimum and then compare, this solution is without pre-sorting, optimizing CPU and memory:

```
public int solution(int[] A, int[] B)
{
//NOTE: Assumption that the array contains at least 2 values, check & handle the different cases properly
    //Take the first 2 values in order
    if(A[0]<A[1]){
        minA=A[0];
        minA2=A[1];
    }else{
        minA=A[1];
        minA2=A[0];
    }

    //Take the first 2 values in order
    if(B[0]<B[1]){
        minB=B[0];
        minB2=B[1];
    }else{
        minB=B[1];
        minB2=B[0];
    }

    //Select the minimum and second minimum of A
    for(int i=0;i<A.Length;i++){
        if(minA>=A[i]){
            minA2=minA;//The previous minimum become the second minimum
            minA=A[i];
        }else if(minA2>A[i]){
            minA2=A[i];//A[i] is the actual second minimum
        }
    }
    //Select the minimum and second minimum of B
    for(int i=0;i<B.Length;i++){
        if(minB>=B[i]){
            minB2=minB;//The previous minimum become the second minimum
            minB=A[i];
        }else if(minB2>B[i]){
            minB2=B[i];//B[i] is the actual second minimum
        }
    }

    //Do your comparison
    return (minA==minB&&minA2==minB2)?minB2:-1;
//NOTE: if you want to check only the second lower: return minA2==minB2?minB2:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in python.

```
#Solution 1
def solution(A, B):
    commonList = [n for n in B if n in A]
    commonList.sort()
    if len(commonList) > 0:
        return commonList[0]
    return -1

#Solution 2
def solution(A, B):
    commonList = []
    for n in A: #Iterates through A and check the elements that appear in B
        if n in B:
            commonList.append(n)
    commonList.sort() 
    #Sort list in order to get minimum value in the first index. 
    #you could use min(commonList) too
    if len(commonList) > 0:
        return commonList[0]
    return -1
```